# SSRS Job Custom steps being deleted

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have added some custom steps to some of my SSRS jobs however they are being removed after a couple of days every time. I know that if you add custom jobs and then change the report or the subscription in the UI then it overwrites the jobs. However they are not being touched yet they are still disappearing.

Has anyone else come across this problem ?

Comment: By SSRS jobs you mean the Subscription schedule job created?

Answer (score 0):

Although I often customize jobs that run subscriptions - no, I haven't come across that problem. I did not customize the jobs that were created automatically, instead I created my own ones.

For a subscription to successfully fire, the name of the job isn't important. Instead, the SQL code to execute the subscription (to be more specific: the SubscriptionID) is what you need to know. Since you were able to find the jobs that execute specific subscriptions, I think that you don't have a problem in finding this information, neither. The code you need looks like this:

```
exec [ReportServer].dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', @EventData='<YourSubscriptionID>'
```

You can use this code in your own jobs as well, and it will work as long as the subscription is there.

The name of the SSRS-generated job is the ID of the *report schedule* that you define for the subscription. This name is needed by SSRS to know where to change the schedule when you change the schedule of the subscription. As you found out, SSRS resets these jobs not only when a subscription is changed. But you don't need all these jobs when creating your own jobs that run the subscription.

To get rid of the auto-generated job with that cryptic name, don't just delete it yourself (as SSRS would re-create it), instead change the schedule of the subscription to a shared schedule that will never run. For this, I created a shared schedule (under site settings) named "Disabled Schedule" and disabled that schedule.

Comment: Not having any luck with this sending out the emails, any suggestions ? The runs with no errors but i have not received an email like i should.

Comment: Check the last status of the subscription, it is displayed in the list of subscriptions for your report in the Report Server Portal. If it says that the report was sent, check the email configuration, also check your spam folder, and finally ask your mail server admins for support in message tracking. Also: please provide the statement you used.